# Is there a sans-serif font that appears different for I (capital i) and l (small L)?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

Is there a sans-serif font that appears different for I  and l? If we are not familiar with "Kim Jong Il", we might spell his name as Kim Jong Two or other incorrect ones.

Comment: *Most* sans-serif fonts have I and l glyphs that look different. Usually, the lowercase l (surprisingly?) is taller than the uppercase I. Separately, the letters may be easy to confuse, but when combined, as in ‘Kim Jong Il’, it’s usually no problem to distinguish them.

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer: I believe that most people cannot notice that l is taller than I even in "Kim Jong Il" (if it is read at a glance). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Many sans serif fonts have tilted lower part of lower case l, e.g. Canatrell.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.google.com/search?q=sans+serif+font+distinguishable+l+I

Comment: The lack of distinction between the uppercase "i" and the lowercase "L" in many sans-serif fonts bothers me. It's a legibility issue. To help mitigate this issue, I am maintaining a simple list of sans-serif fonts which do not have this distinction problem, or at least less of this problem. Maybe I am obsessing over something silly, but here it is: http://www.crossbarifonts.info/

Comment: See the new [Verano Sans](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/verano-sans).

Comment: @isralCDuke The link you provided is dead, site is not even registered anymore, domain is for sale.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [LaTeX2e Font Catalogue: Sans Serif Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html), there is [`venturis`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/venturissans/):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{venturis} %% lf option gives lining figures as default; 
              %% remove option to get oldstyle figures as default
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\begin{document}
Kim Jong Il
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure I would call this sans-serif. Maybe peu de serif.

Answer (score 39):

**Some examples for fonts in T1 font-encoding**

Found in a full MiKTeX installation, but also in my (portable) TeX Live installation:

[image: font test result: fonts with good distinction between I and l]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand*{\test}{W. H. Gates III. | Ill Bill}
\newcommand*{\testfont}[2]{#1: \textsf{\fontfamily{#2}\selectfont\test}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\testfont{Cabin}{Cabin-TLF}

\testfont{Cantarell}{fca}

\testfont{Comfortaa}{fco}

\testfont{Iwona}{iwona}

\testfont{Kp-Sans}{jkpss}

\testfont{PT-Sans}{PTSans-TLF}

- * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * -

\testfont{Tahoma}{tahoma}

\testfont{MS Trebuchet}{trebuchet}% I mixed up the name, it should have been "Trebuchet MS".

\testfont{Verdana}{verdana}

\end{document}
```

If used alone or with their family companions, most of them are called with a `\usepackage` command. For the three fonts below the starred line one needs to manually install the [winfonts](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/winfonts/) package.

---

Just for comparison some fonts with no or only a little distinction between big i and small L:

[image: font test result: fonts with no or slight distinction between I and l]

Comment: Looks like there are two *clear* ways to disambiguate uppercase-i and lowercase-L: add something "horizontal" at both ends of the uppercase-i (as in Tahoma and Verdana above), or add something at the bottom-right of the lowercase-L. Surprising to find that a font that does both seems so hard to find. IMO a font aiming for clarity should never have just a simple vertical bar, for either of the two letters.

Answer (score 12):

Not in TeX Live (not yet, at least), but if you’re using `xetex` or `luatex`, here’s an option: IBM has just released a beta version of its new corporate type family, IBM Plex, containing unambiguous sans as well as monospace and serif fonts, all with real italics and in eight weights. The family is open source and available at [github.com/IBM/plex](https://github.com/IBM/plex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{IBMPlexSans-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
Kim Jong Il
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Another unambiguous sans is [Archia](http://atipofoundry.com/fonts/archia), of which the regular weight is available free with a tweet or a Facebook share (the whole family of six upright weights has a “pay what you want” pricing policy).

[image: sample of Archia]

(There are more samples on [Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/56712911/Archia-typeface).)

Don’t overlook the [Go fonts](https://blog.golang.org/go-fonts) by Bigelow & Holmes, which are available in TeX Live. As Chuck Bigelow explains in his notes (`texmf-dist/doc/fonts/gofonts/gofonts.pdf`), this family conforms to the German DIN 1450 legibility standard, nicely described by [Linotype](https://www.linotype.com/6990/din-1450.html).

[image: sample of Go]

Also noteworthy is [Luciole](http://www.luciole-vision.com/luciole-en.html), which is designed for readers with impaired vision. Its regular, italic, bold, and bold italic are free:

[image: sample of Luciole]

Another typeface for readers with low vision is the free [Atkinson Hyperlegible](https://www.brailleinstitute.org/freefont), from the Braille Institute:

[image: Atkinson Hyperlegible]

**Update**: Thanks to Bob Tennent, [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/plex) now has a package supporting IBM Plex for LaTeX and pdfLaTeX as well as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 9):

What about the new [Source Sans Pro](https://github.com/adobe/Source-Sans-Pro) by Adobe?
[image]

Comment: Yes, I’ve forgotten (but I wrote “examples”).

Answer (score 9):

Another fine choice is the Raleway font, which is available in a recent TeXlive via `\usepackage{raleway}`.  It is interoperable with `pdftex`, but also with the new Unicode engines `xetex` and `luatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{raleway}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
W. H. Gates III. | Ill Bill
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

A true sans-serif font might opt to add a finial to the lower case L, such as
http://www.fonts101.com/search/din+mittel

[image: DIN 1451 Mittelschrift example]

With the usual caveat involved in [using truetype fonts in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex).

Comment: Relevant: http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/366526_obGcDP_CONvBRTEnHCNS8M0g6.pdf

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is that the crossbars on capital `I` are *not* serifs, but are part of the glyph, in the same way that the crossbar on a capital `T` cannot be removed.

Many Serif fonts add *serifs* to the crossbars on a capital `I` to match the *serifs* on the crossbar on the capital `T`; those decorations are serifs, and should be removed in a sans-serif font, but not the crossbars themselves.

Meanwhile, adding the little tail to the bottom of a lower case `l` *is* a serif.

So, when a sans-serif font differentiates `I` from `l` by adding a serif to the `l` but leaves out the crossbars on the `I`, they're doing both letters wrong.

Basically, Tahoma and Verdana are correct fully sans-serif fonts; Helvetica is wrong, and Trebuchet is *very wrong*.

Comment: I agree with everything in the first two paragraphs, and I WOULD agree with the rest if either of the following were true: 1. It were common for serif fonts to add a serif on the bottom of lowercase L that only extends to the right, or 2. the 'tail' at the bottom of lowercase 'L' in these sans serif fonts were either tapered at the tip, or pushed out from the base shape (leaving the bottom of the lowercase 'L' the shape it would be, but with an additional feature tacked on top). However, no Serif font I know of is like that, and sans serif fonts with this actually bend the original shape.

Comment: The 'bending the shape' bit is particularly noteworthy, because a serif is an addition to a shape that can be removed, but that's not how these lowercase 'L's are designed. They're instead designed to curve slightly forward at the bottom, with the glyph staying a more or less constant width. As another argument, consider that you don't call the 'tail' of the Capital 'L' a 'serif', even if it Does 'jut out' as an extra shape tacked on. I consider these sans serif fonts to at most just be shortening the longer tail of the capital 'L', and then rounding corner made at the bend a little bit.

Comment: Actually, I just checked a bunch of serif fonts, and none of the ones I looked at add additional serifs to the cross-bars of the capital 'i'.. But I did finally find one that added a hook on the right side only of the lowercase 'L': "URW Chancery L" and its derivative "TeX Gyre Chorus". Also some of the italic variations of various Serif fonts, and thus likewise with the 'upright italic' variations of a few of those (when present). Since even Chancery is somewhat slanted by default, it's safe to say none that aren't slanted or 'upright italic' are normally like this.

Answer (score 3):

Besides choosing fonts to be used in the document itself, it is also helpful to have a good font for doing the editing work. There it is equally helpful to be able to distinguish characters like o O 0 Q and l I | easily. My recommendation is neither free nor cheap but after switching editing fonts for some time I have setteled with [PragmataPro](http://www.fsd.it/fonts/pragmatapro.htm).

Answer (score 3):

[Noto Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans) has uppercase i with crossbars. Noto Sans is an open font created by Google. See:

[image]

It is worth adding that I wrote a post entitled: [Sans-serif fonts that show uppercase "i" with crossbars to distinguish it from lowercase "l"](https://andarnoespirito.wordpress.com/2022/02/09/sans-fonts-that-show-uppercase-i-with-crossbars-to-differentiate-from-lowercase-l/).

Answer (score 2):

I like Tahoma and Verdana because they have serifs on the capital I, but the rest of the characters are sans-serif.

Answer (score 1):

Segoe UI works as well. I don't know if this font is commonly available. I think it's what my Outlook uses for the calendar, folders, etc.

Comment: Segoe UI is the standard Windows font.  But it looks like between 7 and 8, they changed the font and dropped the serif on the capital 'I'!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Segoe_UI_Revision_Differences.png