# Sans font to go with Bitstream Charter

Tags: fonts, mathdesign

I've been using Bitstream Charter (`\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}`) for a while now. For my German documents, I looked into KOMA today and found that the `scrartcl` document class would be a good replacement for `article`.

It uses sans fonts for the headings and serif font for the text. I got the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

As it seems, I got the Computer Modern Roman sans font for headings, but Charter for the text. I tried Bitstream Vera Sans (Bera Sans, `\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}`). It looks better than before, but I am not sure whether this is a good font to go with Charter:

---

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/12/17/bera.png

---

Is that the matching font or is there a nicer one? It seems pretty thick, especially in the page title.

For comparison, here is plain Computer Modern Roman with `article`:

---

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/12/17/cmr.png

---

And just Charter with `scrartcl`:

---

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/12/17/mixed.png

Comment: Try out some sans-serif fonts. See [LaTeX2e Font Catalogue - Sans Serif Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html) and perhaps [Is there a sans-serif font that appears different for I (capital i) and l (small L)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39543/is-there-a-sans-serif-font-that-appears-different-for-i-capital-i-and-l-small).

Comment: Everybody's complaining about coerced austerity but what's really the worst thing Germany did to the world after WW2 is the serif body text plus bold sans headings default of KOMA. Just my opinion of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not quite a LaTeX question, but Bera looks nice. Linux Biolinum would be a nice option. But you don't necessarily need to use a sans anyway. If you used xelatex you'd have plenty of options, though.

Comment: Libertine and Biolinum look nice in the samples. Question is: Does Libertine work in math mode like Charter does?

Comment: @queueoverflow I recommend `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 2):

The most useful website ever, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), uses Bitstream Charter with Bitstream Vera in its results, which I feel looks nice. (Charter for all math and numbers and Vera for pretty much everything else) Vera is not supported by LaTeX, but luckily there is a clone—[Arev](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/)—that is actually comes with most packages.

Comment: In LaTeX, [I use](https://github.com/martin-ueding/templates/blob/0e8ac0b79eef5ceb5a56904e58ea2ba04af2f292/header.sty#L94) Bitstream Vera Sans as `\usepackage{berasans}` and `\usepackage{beramono}` which works well.

Comment: As of now, WolframAlpha uses Roboto, and Source Sans Pro as sans fonts.