# microtype has issues with mathdesign \mathsf font

Tags: fonts, microtype, mathdesign

I am using

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
```

Sometimes  `\mathsf{...}`  produces

```
 pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
```

Appears when the `\mathsf` is typeset in the end of a line and only with certain characters (e.g. P,..).

So, which fonts does mathdesign use for `\mathsf`? Should I replace it with other font? Suggestions? Solutions?

minimal 'working' example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sdf$\mathsf P$ elementum, elit in varius viverra, mauris augue cursus purus, vel ullamcorper nisi orci pretium nunc.
\end{document}
```

This example is minimal, i.e. dropping `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` avoids the error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please extend your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the error?

Comment: Your MWE runs without errors on my machine (`microtype 2013/03/13 v2.5` and `mathdesign 2006/01/29 v1.55`)

Comment: Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)   (format=pdflatex 2012.12.23), fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g, microtype 2010/01/10 v2.4, mathdesign 2006/01/29 v1.55

Comment: this looks like you should update `microtype`.

Comment: `fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g`, `microtype 2013/03/13 v2.5`, `mathdesign 2006/01/29 v1.55` - the same error massage

Comment: here is a full .log file http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4534615/min.log

Comment: I don't see any significant differences between your log and mine except for the error message. Someone else will have to help...

Comment: @David: Seems like your font setup is broken. You could try to remove and reinstall the charter package: `tlmgr remove charter; tlmgr install charter`.

Comment: Being Debian based, I can't really use `tlmgr`, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73116/29470  
Re-installing the corresponding package (http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/texlive-fonts-recommended) did not help.

Comment: Tried a different machine, same error.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4534615/min2.log

Comment: That log shows the different machine using an even older microtype from 2007.  You need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although closed, I still think this question may be helpful.

This has nothing to do with `microtype`.

`\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`
does not provide sans serif font and the default is used. Type1 version of default font may not be installed (this seems to be the case in standard TeX setup), it is in `cm-super`

See also [Sans font to go with Bitstream Charter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87403/29470) and [Custom typeface for sans serif in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170363/custom-typeface-for-sans-serif-in-math-mode).

Comment: I don't think that moving around the call of `fontenc` does anything. The fact is that you don't have the Type1 version of the default sans serif font, which is available with the CM-Super fonts (to be installed).

Comment: I can not confirm that.

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
...
S\textsf{S}$\mathsf{S}$`

gives [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4534615/mina.png)

`\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
...`

[this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4534615/minb.png)

Installing cm-super solves the issue though. (But the sans serif font is still in wrong scale.)

Seems like cm-super font is not included in 'standard' TeX setup..

Could someone explain what is going on and how to properly use sans serif fonts with mathdesign?