# Why do I suddenly get an auto expansion error?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, mathdesign, font-expansion

On files that have worked previously, I'm suddenly getting the following error

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
```

This error does not appear if I switch back to TexLive-2012, did not appear until recently in TexLive-2013, and seems to be triggered by the use of the `mathdesign` package's `expert` option along with the Charter typeface and `microtype`: that is

```
\RequirePackage[bitstream-charter,expert]{mathdesign}
```

produces the error, while

```
\RequirePackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

does not. To support the `expert` option, I have (purchased) `bchrc8a.pfb` located in `/usr/local/texmf-local/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/`, and if I disable `microtype` I get a different error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file bchrc8a): Font bchrc8a at 600 not found
```

so I suspect that my problems result from TexLive-2103 not finding this file, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

---

This error only appears in fairy complex and lengthy documents, so it is hard for me to produce an good MWE (I'm working on it) but since it seems to be the result of some higher-level configuration issue, I'm hoping that this can be resolved without resorting to a specific example file.

A "partial" MWE, that produces only the second, file not found, error is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\RequirePackage[bitstream-charter,expert]{mathdesign}
%omitting 'expert' above produces no error

\begin{document}    
\textsc{Small Caps}    
Regular text.    
\end{document}
```

In my working files, I use a custom document class based on Tufte-LaTeX, if that rings any bells.

Comment: You should enable the map file relative to the fonts you bought. The easiest way is appending `Map charter.map` (or whatever it's called) to the file `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` (creating it if it doesn't exist) and running `updmap-sys`

Comment: @egreg: So `sudo -H mktexlsr` and `sudo -H updmap-sys` don't do that?

Comment: Not if you first don't tell `updmap-sys` about the new map. With the 2012 distribution you probably ran `updmap-sys --enable-Map charter.map`; the new method with a `updmap.cfg` file also in the `local` tree guarantees that the next major upgrades will find the file and use it automatically.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, the key there is "new method".

Comment: @egreg: I added `Map charter.map` to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` and ran `sudo -H updmap-sys`, but still get the same errors.

Comment: Run `kpsewhich pdftex.map`. Compare the output path with the path of the pdftex.map `updmap-sys` creates. Are the pathes identical? Also check the path of the `updmap.cfg` files `updmap-sys` uses: Is your `updmap.cfg` in the list?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Running `kpsewhich pdftex.map` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`. When I run `updmap-sys` I'm told that "updmap is using ... (in precedence order)", `/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` and `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg`. The contents of the former match what I have in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg`.

Comment: And what is the path of pdftex.map created by updmap-sys?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'm not sure, unless it's the one `updmap-sys` says it is "using ... for writing changes": `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg`.

Comment: No in the output of updmap-sys there should be a block starting with `Files generated:` and then some pathes and map names.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: "Files generated:" `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap`,`/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap`, and `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap`.

Comment: Hm. The path looks ok. But I checked the map files of mathdesign and it is actually quite curious that your file is complaining about `bchrc8a`. You will have to make a minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've added an MWE that partially reproduces the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: See also [microtype has issues with mathdesign \mathsf font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110089) and [pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10706)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I think neither of those is relevant. This is an issue that suddenly appeared (in all my documents, which were unchanged) between runs of TexLive Utility to apply package updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a bug in the virtual font mdbchrc8t.vf: It refers to font `bchrc8a`

```
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME bchrc8a) <---- here
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 6722646267)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

and so the small caps fonts fails (the "font expansion" error is a side-effect of the overall failure). At this place there should be something like `md-chr8t`. Write the author of the fonts a bug report.

Comment: But I do have `bchrc8a.pfb`, located in `/usr/local/texmf-local/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/`, so shouldn't it be found (even if it is being looked for for the wrong reasons)?

Comment: the `vf` is not looking for a `pfb` but for a map entry in the pdftex.map file *starting* with bchrc8a, or another `vf/tfm` or a mf font. The `pfb` is used at the "far end" of the font processing, while the `vf` is somewhere in the middle and the reference to the name of the `pfb` is simply wrong (I checked some other `vf` and they all use names like `md-XXXX` at this place).

Comment: So is the person I should write the author of Charter, or the author of `mathdesign`?

Comment: Imho mathdesign.

Comment: It looks like a bug indeed. I will look at it for the next release. Thank you!

Comment: @PaulPichaureau: Thanks! I'll look for the next release. In the meantime, removing `expert` seems to avoid the problem.

Comment: @PaulPichaureau: FWIW, [installing `xcharter`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144642/7844) seems to get around this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too after upgrading from texlive 2013 to texlive 2014. After adding `\usepackage{XCharter}` (notice the capital XC) in the preamble, I could compile my document again and use the Small Caps Bitstream Charter fonts I had bought.

Comment: This could be taken as as an advertisement to buy some font ;-) It's not clear that this answer does real solve the problem.

Comment: Which part of "After adding \usepackage{XCharter} … I could compile my document again" suggests to you that what I described does not solve the problem? I added the solution which **fixed the problem for me** for other people to benefit from it, as the accepted answer is vague and did _not_ solve the problem for me. I just expanded on raxacoricofallapatorius' helpful hint.