# What are the steps for installing 'xcharter'?

Tags: fonts, packages, installing

I would like to install and use the [`xcharter` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/xcharter), but am unclear on the steps involved. There are [what appear to be instructions](http://ctan.mackichan.com/fonts/xcharter/README) provided with the package, but I don't understand them.

Is it sufficient to install the package using Tex Live Utility (on OS 10.9), or are there additional steps required to build and place fonts in various directories? Will the installation disturb any existing fonts?

Comment: Using Tex Live Utility (or `tlmgr`) to install `xcharter` should suffice and cause no problems.

Comment: @DG': Do I need to run anything after Tex Live Utility, or is that sufficient?

Comment: You should be good to go.

Comment: @DG': Generalized a bit to the steps needed to install a package that includes fonts, this could be an accepted answer.

Comment: Note that installing `xcharter` gets around a [bug in `mathdesign`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135275/7844).

Comment: Info for MiKTeX users: `xcharter` can be installed with the Package Manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see there are four different cases. The first three cases concern fonts with direct LaTeX support (there are packages) with different licenses, while the fourth addresses fonts without direct LaTeX support, no matter how they are licensed:

**a) Free fonts in the TL repository like `xcharter`**

On a well maintained, recent distribution like TL2013 on MacOS it is very likely, that simply updating your system with the TeX Live Utility will install everything needed.

If you don’t have a full installation, just install the package with TeX Live Utility or by running `sudo tlmgr install xcharter` in a terminal. (The instructions on font installation, which are often found in the documentation of font packages, are only of import *if* you are not using a package manager.)

This applies to a whole range of fonts like `dejavu`, `utopia`, `libertine`, `mathpazo` and `gentium` to name just a few.

**b) Non-free fonts like `garamondx`**

There is a number of fonts, including `garamondx`, which can be installed using the script `getnonfreefonts`. In order to do so, follow the instructions [here](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/).

**c) Non-free fonts with LaTeX support like `Minion Pro`**

Other popular fonts like `Minion Pro` have [LaTeX support](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minionpro) but need to be installed manually. Usually there are detailed instructions accompanying the packages. In some cases, like Minion Pro, you can even find [scripts](http://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2012/11/10/installing-minion-pro/) that do the work for you.

**d) Fonts without direct support**

There is a huge class of commercial and free fonts without direct LaTeX support. They can be used with [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) (this option requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX).

More on manual font installation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

---

So, to generalize a bit: *if* a package contains a font *and* the package is in the TL repository *then* installing it with a package manager (like `tlmgr`) should suffice.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work after all, I get "! LaTeX Error: Font family 'T1+XCharter-OsF' unknown." if I have `\usepackage[scaled=.96,osf]{XCharter}` (taken directly from the documentation) in my document. It doesn't look as of the fonts are being found after all.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The installation of `xcharter`is straight forward, so I suspect the error lies elsewhere. Try the following steps to figure out, what went wrong: 1. Update your installation: `sudo tlmgr update --all --self`. 2. Reinstall `xcharter`: `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall xcharter`. 3. Run: `sudo updmap-sys --syncwithtrees`.

Comment: My bad: My issues had nothing to do with the `xcharter` installation and everything do to with some lines in my template that messed with bolding (e.g.: `\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{sb}{n}{<->ssub*\rmdefault/bx/n}{}`). If I remove those lines `charter` works. I'm not sure what I've lost by removing them, but I don't see anything at first glance.

Comment: Glad to see the mystery solved. The code you are mentioning seems to [redefine bold as semi bold](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47883/how-can-i-redefine-bold-to-mean-semi-bold), which results in error as there is no semi-bold charter.

Comment: Prior to installing `xcharter`, this redefinition worked, with the same `mathdesign` options I'm using now (`[charter, expert,euro]`.I would like to have semi-bold replace bold. Why did it work before and not now?

Comment: Actually, that code is trying to substitute bold for semi-bold when semi-bold is not available. Does charter even have semi-bold? I can't find it defined in the mathdesign font definition files.

Answer (score 2):

To install the xcharter font for `Texlive`, I did the following (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

1. Download the TDS-structured trees for the font packages from `CTAN`, e.g. xcharter.tds.zip. Unzip it to your personal directory `$TEXMFHOME` or system directory, i.e.:

   `unzip -d xcharter.tds.zip ~/texmf/`
2. Update the database (no root, no sudo), i.e.:

   `texhash ~/texmf/`
3. Update the font-map files by enabling the Map file XCharter.map:

   `updmap -enable MAP=XCharter.map`

OR alternatively, manually edit your font-map file "updmap.cfg", in my case, it is located at ~/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg, just simply add a new line into the file:

Map XCharter.map

Done.
In general, these steps would work for installing most of the latex fonts downloaded from CTAN into your TexLive system.

Keywords: latex, install fonts, ctan, ubuntu, texlive

Reference:
https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall-personal.html

Comment: the unzip command is wrong, the correct form is: `unzip -d ~/texmf/ xcharter.tds.zip`