# Custom typeface for sans serif in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif, mathdesign

How to set custom typeface for sans serif in math mode for pdfLaTeX?

Background: I use `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}` which does not provide sans serif font, CM-super is used instead for sans serif typeface. This font does not fit well with Charter (different scale,..) so I want to try alternatives (Bera, Biolinum, Luxi Sans, ..??).

Example..

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}  %fix [noamsfonts] bug
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    $\mathsf A$ % I want to change this typeface
\end{document}
```

Comment: pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX handle fonts very differently. Your question suggests you are mostly concerned with pdfLaTeX (or are not using the enhanced font facilities of XeLaTeX). Either way, please post a **Minimal Working Example** i.e. the code for a small, compilable document which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Yes, these are two different questions, I would like to know answers for both, but more interested in pdfLaTeX.

Comment: The question for XeLaTeX depends a lot on the rest of your configuration. That's another reason a MWE is so important. Are you using `mathunicode`? `fontspec`? opentype versions of the fonts?

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining. I will edit the question to ask only for pdfLaTeX.

Comment: You probably want `[utf8]{inputenc}` rather than `[utf8x]{inputenx}`, by the way.

Comment: OK,[`[utf8]` vs `[utf8x]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc). Why `inputenc` rather than `inputenx`? The only info I found is `(inputenx) serves as more up­to­date re­place­ment for pack­age in­pu­tenc.'

Comment: I think you are right. I really meant the `utf8` versus `utf8x` thing. I think I somehow associated the `x` in `inputenx` with the `x` in `utf8x`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want something like this?

EDIT: The following code is edited to eliminate loading `charter` which turns out to be pointless. `mathdesign` wants to set `\rmdefault` to `mdbch` rather than `bch` - so let it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fvs}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm}
\usepackage[charter, sfscaled, ttscaled]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow!

\textsf{Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow!}

\texttt{Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow!}

\[
  E=m\mathrm{c}^2
\]
\[
  \mathrm{roman\ maths}\ \mathsf{sans\ maths}\ \mathtt{typewriter\ maths}\ \mathbf{bold\ maths}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Charter, Bera & Bera]

## XCharter

Thanks to Manuel's comment, I discovered a relatively new extension of Charter provided by the `XCharter` package (yes, it is capitalised). Based on the package documentation, I tried this to adjust the sizing appropriately:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fvs}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm}
\usepackage[charter, expert, sfscaled, ttscaled]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled=.96,osf]{XCharter}% matches the size used in math
\linespread{1.04}

\begin{document}
Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789

\textsf{Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789}

\texttt{Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789}

\[
  E=m\mathrm{c}^2
\]
\[
   0123456789
\]
\[
 \mathrm{roman\ maths}\ \mathsf{sans\ maths}\ \mathtt{typewriter\ maths}\ \mathbf{bold\ maths}
\]

\textsc{\itshape Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789}

\textsc{Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789}

\textsc{\itshape\bfseries Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789}

\textsc{\textbf{Oh sphinx of black quartz, hear my vow! 0123456789}}

\end{document}
```

[image: XCharter with mathdesign]

It is worth noting that the manual doesn't really recommend using `mathdesign`. For an alternative, see example 2 on page 2 of [XCharter](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcharter)'s manual.

Comment: With this setup, does the font for regular text come from the `charter` package or `mathdesign`? Switching the order of `\usepackage{charter}` and `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` produces different outputs. Also, the latter setup complains about `Font shape T1/bch/m/fsc undefined(Font)` .. (small caps?)

Comment: @DCh See my edit. Loading `charter` was wrong. It turns out that `mathdesign` wants to set `\rmdefault` to `mdbch` (rather than `bch`). So you got different output because loading `charter` first has no effect - `mathdesign` overwrites the setting - but loading it second means it clobbers `mathdesign`'s setting. So not loading it at all is the solution. I can't reproduce the error you mention bu not loading `charter` should eliminate it. It happens because `bch`, unlike `mdbch`, doesn't have an `fsc` shape. I don't know what `fsc` is. The files define `sc` (as usual) for small-caps.

Comment: I would personally load `XCharter` after the math package, so you get a fully enhaced text font.

Comment: @Manuel I wasn't aware of `XCharter` - thanks. Although it looks nice, I don't think it is a good solution here because I believe the OP is using Debian's TL which I'm guessing will not have this package. However, I should probably add it in for other users as an option for those with current installations... I **do** wish people would not use capitals in package names, though!

Comment: @Manuel See my edit...

Comment: @Manuel Hmm... I tried to keep to what `mathdesign` supported since the question was how to use it with sans serif fonts... Thanks! EDIT: Also, thanks. I always forget the pesky mirrors.

Comment: @cfr `mathdesign` defines `fsc` for fake small caps, which are then used instead of `sc`. The `expert` option prevents this. Good guess with Debian's TL and not having `XCharter` (but it looks interesting though). Thanks, your help is appreciated!

Comment: @DCh Ah, right! Thanks - that makes sense. I couldn't figure out why they defined `fsc` as well as `sc` but the expert/non-expert option makes sense of that.